# Is it possible to display distinct record from dataset in RDLC report

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, dataset, rdlc

Did a quick search and couldn't find the answer I've been looking for.
So I have a vb.net windows application which uses RDLC to generate invoice, delivery order, price list and other documents. To reduce server load as much as possible, information will only be pulled once from the server and it includes order items, price and other necessary data.

Once the data is pulled (in xml) it will be filled into a dataset which will be used in generating various reports. Note that this same dataset is used in multiple RDLC reports to display different information.

So the problem in my case is that I cannot do a SELECT DISTINCT from the SQL level because the same set of data will also be used generate the invoice, but I also need to display a price list from the same dataset which only include distinct order items.

So the options I have:

1. Have the RDLC to display distinct row, but I have no idea on how it can be achieved.
2. Failing that, I might need to create another datatable in my xsd file using the existing dataset, separating the dataset into 2. Again, I have little idea on the details of execution.

Any input is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I'll let you know what I usually do. I create multiple DataSets to split my information in clearer and smaller DataTables. Then, I just create multiple report datasources and link the datasets to them. If that's something you're looking for, I could provide you some code on how I did it.

Comment: Yes please I believe thats exactly what I've been looking for. At the moment, my application has only one dataset (and one datasource) which match the schema of the xml file returned from the server.
The code used to bind the data is something like
`xml.ReadXml(New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(xmlString))) _ 
delivery_order_itemBindingSource.DataSource = xml`
xml being the xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will contain **three** `DataSets`. Since we have three DataSets, I'll use **three** `DataSources` in **one** *Report.rdlc*. The scenario will be a simple production line. We'll have starting machines, machines that are being assembled and also machines who are getting shipped.

I'll assume you know how to create DataSets (.XSD) files. I will split up the code into sections and show you the final result in this post.

What is important to your question is how I assign three DataSources to one report.

---

### Declarations

I have three custom classes, `clsAssemblyState`, `clsExpeditionState`, `clsStartState` which hold information that is gathered from the Database. These are just my custom classes which I use as objects. You bind your data with XML, I assign it programmatically as you'll see below in the "**Filling DataTables Programmatically**" section.

```
Dim ds1 As New dsAssemblies 'Link to my DataSet called dsAssemblies'
Dim ds2 As New dsExpeditions 'Link to my DataSet called dsExpeditions'
Dim ds3 As New dsStarts 'Link to my DataSet called dsStarts'
Dim sReportDataSource1 As ReportDataSource 'First datasource'
Dim sReportDataSource2 As ReportDataSource 'Second datasource'
Dim sReportDataSource3 As ReportDataSource 'Third datasource'
Dim AssemblyStates As List(Of clsAssemblyState) = clsAssemblyState.GetAll() 'List that contains all my machines being assembled'
Dim ExpeditionStates As List(Of clsExpeditionState) = clsExpeditionState.GetAll() 'List that  contains all my machines in shipping'
Dim StartStates As List(Of clsStartState) = clsStartState.GetAll() 'List of all my machines being started (paper work)'
```

---

### Reseting the report

It is good practice to clear your report datasource before assigning new ones.

```
'Reset the viewer'
rv.Reset()
rv.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourProjectName.YourReportName.rdlc"
rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
sReportDataSource1 = New ReportDataSource()
sReportDataSource2 = New ReportDataSource()
sReportDataSource3 = New ReportDataSource()
```

---

### Filling DataTables Programmatically

This will fill my dsAssemblies' DataTable, the same is done for the other two DataTables but it would be redundant for me to write this out here.

```
'Fill datatables'
If AssemblyStates.Count > 0 Then
    For Each asmState As clsAssemblyState In AssemblyStates
        Dim asm As New clsAssembly(asmState.FK_Assembly)
        Dim Machine As New clsMachine(asm.FK_Machine)
        Dim Client As New clsClient(Machine.FK_Client)
        Dim State As New clsState(asmState.FK_State)

        ds1.dtAssembly.Rows.Add(Machine.MachineNo, Machine.Description, Client.Nom, State.State, asm.DateTransfer.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    Next
Else
    'No information was retrieved from my GetAll(), therefor no rows ... I add a row with values of "N/A" notifying the user that there is nothing in that particular DataTable'
    ds1.dtAssembly.Rows.Add("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")
End If
```

---

### Assign DataTables to DataSources

The `sReportDataSource[i].Name` are the names that I assigned to each DataTable of it's respective DataSet. I will show a picture of the DataSets below the code.

```
sReportDataSource1.Name = "Assembly_DataSet"
sReportDataSource2.Name = "Expedition_DataSet"
sReportDataSource3.Name = "Start_DataSet"
sReportDataSource1.Value = ds1.dtAssembly
sReportDataSource2.Value = ds2.dtExpedition
sReportDataSource3.Value = ds3.dtStart
rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource1)
rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource2)
rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource3)
rv.RefreshReport()
Me.Show()
```

Here you see the three DataSets and their DataTables

[image: DataSets]

---

### Full Report Code

This method will generate a report using three datasources. Of course, you must assign those DataSets to something in your `.rdlc` such as three different tablix.

```
Private Sub GenerateStatusProduction()
    Dim ds1 As New dsAssemblies
    Dim ds2 As New dsExpeditions
    Dim ds3 As New dsStarts
    Dim sReportDataSource1 As ReportDataSource
    Dim sReportDataSource2 As ReportDataSource
    Dim sReportDataSource3 As ReportDataSource
    Dim AssemblyStates As List(Of clsAssemblyState) = clsAssemblyState.GetAll()
    Dim ExpeditionStates As List(Of clsExpeditionState) = clsExpeditionState.GetAll()
    Dim StartStates As List(Of clsStartState) = clsStartState.GetAll()

    'Reset the viewer'
    rv.Reset()
    rv.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourProjectName.YourReportName.rdlc"
    rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    sReportDataSource1 = New ReportDataSource()
    sReportDataSource2 = New ReportDataSource()
    sReportDataSource3 = New ReportDataSource()

    'Fill datatables'
    If AssemblyStates.Count > 0 Then
        For Each asmState As clsAssemblyState In AssemblyStates
            Dim asm As New clsAssembly(asmState.FK_Assembly)
            Dim Machine As New clsMachine(asm.FK_Machine)
            Dim Client As New clsClient(Machine.FK_Client)
            Dim State As New clsState(asmState.FK_State)

            ds1.dtAssembly.Rows.Add(Machine.MachineNo, Machine.Description, Client.Nom, State.State, asm.DateTransfer.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        Next
    Else
        ds1.dtAssembly.Rows.Add("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")
    End If

    If ExpeditionStates.Count > 0 Then
        For Each expdState As clsExpeditionState In ExpeditionStates
            Dim Expd As New clsExpedition(expdState.FK_Expedition)
            Dim Machine As New clsMachine(Expd.FK_Machine)
            Dim Client As New clsClient(Machine.FK_Client)
            Dim State As New clsState(expdState.FK_State)

            ds2.dtExpedition.Rows.Add(Machine.MachineNo, Machine.Description, Client.Nom, State.State, Expd.DateTransfer.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        Next
    Else
        ds2.dtExpedition.Rows.Add("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")
    End If

    If StartStates.Count > 0 Then
        For Each strtState As clsStartState In StartStates
            Dim Strt As New clsStart(strtState.FK_Start)
            Dim Machine As New clsMachine(Strt.FK_Machine)
            Dim Client As New clsClient(Machine.FK_Client)
            Dim State As New clsState(strtState.FK_State)

            ds3.dtStart.Rows.Add(Machine.MachineNo, Machine.Description, Client.Nom, State.State, Strt.DateTransfer.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        Next
    Else
        ds3.dtStart.Rows.Add("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")
    End If

    sReportDataSource1.Name = "Assembly_DataSet"
    sReportDataSource2.Name = "Expedition_DataSet"
    sReportDataSource3.Name = "Start_DataSet"
    sReportDataSource1.Value = ds1.dtAssembly
    sReportDataSource2.Value = ds2.dtExpedition
    sReportDataSource3.Value = ds3.dtStart
    rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource1)
    rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource2)
    rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource3)
    rv.RefreshReport()
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

Note: `rv` is my report viewer control name instead of `ReportViewer1`

Answer (score 2):

After a few experiments I've managed to find a better (and easier) solution for the problem. It is probably the most elegant solution so far. So I figured that I post it here for others who ran into the same problem.

This is how the report looks in the designer
[image]
The green marking shows the respective row group and tablix row. The same item_id may exists in more than 1 line/row and I need to have them shown distinct. This can be done by using the grouping feature under the row group properties.
[image]
Under group expressions, add a new entry and select the field which needs to be shown distinct. It supports expressions too which is very very useful.
[image]